# React Router Link Element Breaking Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, react-router

I have been working on a personal project and recently learned react and packages. I have been looking the past few days at how to fix a problem I have been having with the Link component in React Router but cant find anyone with my problem. Let me begin by saying that I have everything installed correctly and nothing should be conflicting with it, I followed the documentation closely. Essentially when I use `<Link>` in my code the entirety of the header doesn't display and I get a blank page with no errors. I tried replacing link with `<a>` and `<div>` tags and everything shows up fine but just not with the `<Link>`

Here is the problem code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <div class="row" id="pageHeader">
        <div class="col-0 col-lg-2"></div> {/* spacer for begining of header */}

        {/* code for company logo and link back to home page */}
        <div class="col-auto">
          <Link to="/Home">
            <img src="./images/dnf - logo.png" alt="DNF - Logo" /> {/* logo */}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h6 class="mt-2">Get It Done Right,<br />The First Time.</h6> {/* Header slogan */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

If anyone knows the issue to this please help I don't know what, if anything, is wrong with my code.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code. What version of the `react-router-dom` is installed? Are there any errors? Are you saying that when using the `Link` component that `NavBar` component renders nothing?

Comment: You tried use `<Link to"home" >` (no in CamelCase) ? You have created a route to `/home` ? Please put this informations besides the version of `react-router-dom`

Comment: Is any error get in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Link tag and image with a Router tag.

```
<Router>
  <Link to="/Home">
    <img src="./images/dnf - logo.png" alt="DNF - Logo" /> {/* logo */}
  </Link>
</Router>
```

Don't forget to import

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file where you import router, import **BrowserRouter** instead of just *Router*.

```
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter as  Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

Also you have to use the `<Link />` inside a `<Router>` component.

```
  <Router >
    <NavBar />  {/* the component which uses <Link /> */}
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

In my case it worked!

Just try to use the browser developer console to get more idea about the error.